# No type or protocol named 'AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate' in -Swift.h header file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, avfoundation

I have an Objective-C Project in which I use Swift scripts amongst Obj-C scripts.

In one of the Swift scripts I have a class:

```
@objc public class VideoCapture: NSObject, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
~~bunch of functions~~
}
```

Because it's an Obj-C project, I prepended it with @obj, so that they appear in my ($project_name-Swift.h) header file.

I get the error for what's written in my header file:

// snippet from header file: project_name-Swift.h

```
 #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>.  <— I added this to make sure that AVFoundation is present in the header file

SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC17FLIROneSDKExample12VideoCapture")
@interface VideoCapture : NSObject <AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>   <<——!!! error: No type or protocol named 'AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate'
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput * _Nonnull)output didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef _Nonnull)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection * _Nonnull)connection;
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput * _Nonnull)output didDropSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef _Nonnull)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection * _Nonnull)connection;
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

I don't understand what's causing it, and I guess it has to do with not being able to access the AVFoundation library from the header file correctly or something.

Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue. Adding the `@objc` or `@protocol` doesn't help. I solve it by adding

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

to the `PrefixHeader.pch` file just before `#import <project_name-Swift.h>`.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely helped me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to add the `@protocol` for `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`.

```
@protocol AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate;
```

Put that just above `@interface` in your `project_name-Swift.h` file.

Comment: Adding this doesn't solve the problem, nor changes the error code unfortunately. You meant just adding this line in the header file riight? Or also add a protocol in my .swift file? Also, is it even okay to change this -Swift.h file? It seems that xcode undoes my changes there every time I clean with Cmd + shift + k

Comment: Try adding that to your `Swift` file; regarding the undoing changes -- no idea.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that correctly. This is not correct is it? : 

`@objc public protocol AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate{}`

Answer (score 1):

Try using @objcMembers on top of your swift imported class, this will make sure you will get access to all objective-c code.

Comment: Thanks! prepended it to my class, like
`@objcMembers public class VideoCapture: NSObject, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {`
But it's unfortunately still not working . 
I get in my -swift header file:  `@interface VideoCapture : NSObject <AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate> <-- error No type or protocol named 'AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate'`

Comment: Try to replace this delegate with other that do compile ok and look for differences. If problem not solved then please share the h file header of this problematic delegate.

Comment: I've tried the same with AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate, and get the same error. Additionally, when adding @objcMembers, I get some expected type errors as well on parts of the code. This happens in the file included from my .m file where I import the -Swift.h file. Do you mean to share my own -Swift.h file?

Answer (score -1):

In my case: add @protocol youdelegate; into the -Bridging-Header.h file.